# Missing google_app_id. Firebase Analytics disabled

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-analytics

I have created a new Flutter project and created Firebase apps using `flutterfire configure`, Analytics works perfectly fine in iOS, but the android app didin't trigger analytics even a single time. It's been 7 days. Initially, i thought the delay in event but it's not working at all.

I have added Crashlytics as well, but that's working for both Android and iOS.

`<project>/build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // Google services
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

...other stuff
```

`<project>/app/build.gradle`

```
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

...other stuff
```

as for error information, I'm only getting

> E/FA      (15604): Missing google_app_id. Firebase Analytics disabled.
> See ####

**Tried so far**

1. Manually added `google-services.json`
2. Manually added `google_app_id` in `strings.xml`
3. I have added manually in both `build.gradle` files, `flutterfire configure` not adding anything in these files
4. Using the latest version of `flutterfire` = `0.2.7`

Can anyone help me to add Firebase analytics in flutter app?